# Updating a datarow in a datatable within code

Tags: c#, ado.net, datatable, datarow

I'm trying to do something that you would think is pretty straight forward. I'm retrieving a record from a database for display in a detailsview. However, before I display the record to the user I want to remove the timestamp of a dateTime value. So I tried to do the following by creating a function that takes the column name and the data row instance.

```
protected void FormatDateFromRow(string columnName, DataRow row)
        {
        if (row[columnName] != DBNull.Value)
        {
            DateTime dateTime;
            bool result = DateTime.TryParse(row[columnName].ToString(), out dateTime);

            if (result)
            {
                row.BeginEdit();
                row[columnName] =  dateTime.ToShortDateString();
                row.EndEdit();
                row.AcceptChanges();
            }
        }

    }
```

I'm using this method in a piece of logic that looks like this.

```
            if (dt != null)
            {
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0 && dt.Columns.Contains("SystemName"))
                {
                    DataRow row = dt.Rows[0];

                    lblHeader.Text = row["SystemName"].ToString();

                     FormatDateFromRow("GrantedDate", row);
                     FormatDateFromRow("ExpireDate", row);
                     dt.AcceptChanges();

                    dvPackage.DataSource = dt;
                    dvPackage.DataBind();
                }
```

But when the detailsView is displayed the timestamp is still present. Can some one please help?

Thanks,
GS

Comment: Of what type are the columns you pass to your format methods? If you read a DateTime and try to store a string I wonder why this is not throwing an exception...

Comment: The columns in the database are DateTime but the string I'm passing into my method for formatting is the string name of the column.

Comment: The conversion works fine. When I add dateTime.ToShortDateString();
 to the watch list it returns the value that I want to store in the r[columnName] but when I assign it like

Comment: The conversion works fine. When I add dateTime.ToShortDateString();
 to the watch list it returns the value that I want to store in the r[columnName] but when I assign it like

Comment: row[columnName] = dateTime.ToShortDateString();
 the value does not persist and is replaced by the original value.

Comment: Why do you modify the DataSource directly? Instead you should format your values at the very last place(f.e. via [DateTime.ToShortDateString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring.aspx) or `myDate.ToString("d")`). If you don't need the exact value at all, then you should convert it in your sql.

Answer (score 2):

I *suppose* your conversion to `DateTime` somehow fails on this line:

`bool result = DateTime.TryParse(row[columnName].ToString(), out dateTime)`;

Check out if this line returns a `true`. If not consider using correct `Culture` in order to be able to convert.

[DateTime.TryParse Method (String, IFormatProvider, DateTimeStyles, DateTime)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9h21f14e.aspx)

Hope this helps.

Comment: my conversion works fine. Whe I add it to the watch list it contains the value I want. it is only when I assign it to row[columnName] that the value does not persist prior to databinding to the detailsView.